# Structuring a MySQL table where the PLAYLIST table refers to multiple VIDEO id integers and a USER table id

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, pdo

I want to retrieve one complete object from VIDEOPLAYLIST that contains the complete USER object and all the VIDEO objects related to it.

I understand that I will need to use LEFT JOIN to merge them, but I cant understand how i should setup my PLAYLIST table and how to query it when it comes to multiple VIDEO id's.

This is my current database EER Diagram:
[image: Original EER Diagram of my database tables]

Should I create a many to many relationship between the playlist and video?
Should I somehow store all the VIDEO id's in the PLAYLIST table?
And then how would be able to query it?

This is where I'm stuck:

```
SELECT * FROM videoplaylist LEFT JOIN user LEFT JOIN video ON user.id = playlist.user_id AND videos....
```

PS. I won't just be querying one PLAYLIST at the time, as I need to display them in a list format.

Comment: Thanks, now I'm one step closer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should create a many-to-many relationship between the video and playlist table if you want that one video could be added to multiple playlists and vice versa.

So your many-to-many relationship table could look like this where the combination of `playlist_id` and `video_id` is your primary key.

```
playlist_has_video
------------------
playlist_id
video_id
```

If you want to be able to add a video more than once to a playlist you have to create an id col in this table too. So now `id` is your primary key.

```
playlist_has_video
------------------
id
playlist_id
video_id
```

When you want to enable the user to sort the playlist think about adding another col `order_id` to your n-to-m table.

```
playlist_has_video
------------------
id
playlist_id
video_id
order_id
```

Now lets see the select queries (i will refer to the last design, `id` + `order_id`)

retrieving all videos from a playlist:

```
SELECT video.* FROM playlist_has_video AS phv LEFT JOIN video ON phv.video_id = video.id WHERE phv.playlist_id = :playlist_id ORDER BY order_id ASC;
```

Retrieving all playlists the video is in:

```
SELECT playlist.* FROM playlist_has_video AS phv LEFT JOIN playlist ON phv.playlist_id = playlist.id WHERE phv.video_id = :video_id;
```

You have to alter you video - table too if you use this approach (Make sure you remove playlist_id)

```
video
---------
id
title
description
user_id
transcript_id
created
updated
```

Comment: Not bad for 8 minutes.

Comment: @Strawberry: Haha thanks. I drank a lot of coffee today :D

Comment: You were too fast, Stackoverflow won't let me approve this as the solution yet haha.

Comment: @sciencefyll: No problem. Make sure to use my updated answer. I've added a more specific SELECT to the queries so you only will retrieve the desired data.

Comment: @TobiasKun shouldn't it be: playlist - 1:n - playlist_has_video - n:1 - video?

Comment: @sciencefyll: Yes, this is called an n-to-m relationship. That's why you added the extra table.